# Looking for examples of accesing IndexedDB from several scripts

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, web-worker

I'm trying to implement job processor using workers in background.

I will store some job-related information in IndexedDB.

I tried to find some information, related to *accessing same IndexedDB database from multiple scripts*, multiple workers in my case, *stuff with version change explained* in that case, but could find anything useful.

I need some information on that topic...

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! right now, this question is too broad to fit the SO question and answer format. please consider refining it and/or taking it to one of the other forums such as programmers which is more fit for this kind of question.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman thanks for your suggestion. I will try to improve my question

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [my IDB library as an example](https://github.com/editor/dash/blob/master/lib/dash.dev.js#L1242) of IDB in Web Workers.

Things to note:

- IDB in a Web Worker does not work in Firefox. Although the spec says it should allow async access (not to mention non-existing sync access), and the Mozilla IDB dev is championing their ticket for this, Mozilla's bug tracker suggests to me lots of issues need to be worked out and that this won't be available in the near future (as of 3/2014)
- Like IDB when it stores data, Web Workers use a structured clone algo to pass data between worker thread and parent. This means that all your objects need to be cloneable. So you need to transform `IDBObjectstore`, `DOMStringList`, etc. into plain vanilla JS objects.

Otherwise, IDB in Web Workers is great. Personally I think this is the best way to fetch data without any chance of locking the UI.

Comment: Not really following. The sync IDB API is deprecated? or can you now use the async IDB API in a web worker? One way or another since IDB is async it shouldn't really matter if you are using it in the UI thread.

Comment: Per spec, all browsers that support IDB should eventually support both async and sync in Web Workers. Sync API hasn't arrived yet in any browser. Only the async API has yet been implemented. You can indeed use the async API in a Web Worker today, but not yet in Firefox.